# Is there a way to integrate a processing sketch written in Python in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, processing

The title says it all.

I spent a lot of time designing a sketch in Processing using the Python language.

Now, I would like to put the sketch on a webpage.

Of course, I could just translate the sketch from python language to javascript and use a javascript library for processing.

However, this would be a very lengthy process. As such, do you know if there is a way to integrate a python sketch in the website? If yes, how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no straightforward way to do this. But some workarounds can be found. For example, since Processing's python mode is using Jython language (Python on JVM) you can do the following:

1. Compile the Jython code to Java bytecode
2. Decompile Java bytecode to real Java code
3. Use processing.js to make the sketch run in a webpage

Of course, there are chances that the generated Java code will not be 100% Processing code, thus will not be converted to Javascript by the processing.js library.